# Are all trains/buses within the EU non-smoking? What about smoking on platforms?

Tags: public-transport, trains, legal, buses, eu

No, I'm not a smoker, but some friends coming on a trip with me are, and they want to know what their options are (I suppose some of the 12+ hour journeys we have planned frighten them).

Personally, I hope it's banned everywhere, but you never know.

Let's limit it to the EU and the EEA. We can assume that *most* places prohibit smoking on the train, so let's hear if there are any exceptions, and which countries forbid smoking in the station (the UK is one, I believe).

Comment: What is the EEA?

Comment: the European Economic Area, so basically the EU + Norway, Liechtenstein and Iceland.

Comment: Ah I see. Now I can add an answer.

Comment: In the Czech Republic you can't smoke even in open stations.

Comment: @victoriah Does Switzerland not come under the EEA ?

Comment: No, Switzerland is not part of the EEA, but can be included for the purposes of discussion.

Comment: You will often see reference to EU+EEA+CH, for example at passport control when entering Europe.

Answer (score 10):

I am not a smoker. But I know that I am annoyed by the smell of stinking smokers at Dutch railway stations where designated smoking areas are installed on almost all platforms. They are recognizable as iron totem pals surrounded by smoking worshippers.

Comment: In the few German stations I've been to they also have this.

Answer (score 9):

I can only answer this question for a small part of the countries you're interested in.

Liechtenstein does not have its own rail service, so the Austrian respectively the Swiss rules apply here. Nevertheless there are some railway stations in Liechtenstein that are mainly served by Austrian trains. In all Austrian and Swiss trains it is strictly forbidden to smoke and the fines are quite high (some hundred francs).

Concerning smoking in railway stations there is a similar rule: It is forbidden if the railway station is a closed room. So if for example there are some underground passages you're not allowed to smoke there. But on the platform you're allowed to smoke. In Liechtenstein there are only platforms without roofs or walls, so you can smoke there everywhere.

Concerning buses, the same rule applies. Strictly forbidden in all buses but possible on bus station if they are not covered by a roof and walls.

Answer (score 8):

In Germany some long-distance or express trains have separate smoking compartments inside the train, and sections on the platforms where smoking is allowed - however nobody really cares where you smoke on the platform if there are ashtrays on top of the rubbish bins.

Smoking is generally prohibited in all trains and buses in Germany; train stations restrict smoking to designated smoking areas that are usually available on all platforms (though, I should note, the latter restriction is hardly ever enforced); there's a wide selection of long-distance buses available in Germany now, though while they are sometimes cheaper than trains, their stops are sometimes outside of cities, they are slower, and each bus company has its own tickets, so you sometimes need several tickets (and thus get no connection guarantee).

From my experience Germany is a bit more smoker-friendly than the rest of (West-) Europe, and last time i checked they even still allowed tobacco companies to advertise in public places, bus stops and so on. It was just recently when they passed a law that would forbid smoking in some restaurants because of health concerns for the employees who work there 40h/week or more; but about 10 years ago it was pretty much impossible to go to a pub in Germany and don't smell like an ashtray when you came out later that night.

Comment: Ha! I always wondered this about Germany, why there were no long distance buses. In France it's much worse though so you've prompted me to ask [a question about it](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3375/why-does-there-seem-to-be-no-long-distance-buses-in-france)!

Comment: The ruling parties in Germany agreed to lift the bars on long distance buses during the current term (2009-2013), though. The railroad company Deutsche Bahn also is no longer state-owned (since 1994). So the availability of long-distance buses in Germany should improve in the near future.

Comment: Actually there are no trains with smoking compartments anymore in Germany, but still there is a smoking spot on nearly every platform.

Comment: @al. Deutsche Bahn is a privately organized company but still is owned 100% by the federal state.

Comment: The updated version of this answer should read: Smoking is generally prohibited in all trains and buses in Germany; train stations restrict smoking to designated smoking areas that are usually available on all platforms (though, I should note, the latter restriction is hardly ever enforced); there's a wide selection of long-distance buses available in Germany now, though while they are sometimes cheaper than trains, their stops are sometimes outside of cities, they are slower, and each bus company has its own tickets, so you sometimes need several tickets (and thus get no connection guarantee)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, can you please post an answer, based on what you wrote here with maybe adjustments for now if different? There is a bounty on this question, just because the answers are so behind the facts.

Answer (score 6):

In the UK smoking is forbidden everywhere on the railway network: in trains, on platforms and in stations. It's tolerated outside in the street, but that's all.

Comment: Smoking on platforms away from the buildings is pretty common though and difficult to police.

Comment: Some stations (e.g. Reading in the UK) have smoke detectors on the platforms: a recorded announcement plays if they're triggered.

Comment: Trivia time! There is one station on the national network on which smoking is allowed - Fishguard Harbour. This is because, unlike most stations on the network, this station is privately owned by Stena Line (the ferry company who operate from Fishguard). The platforms are open, and so Stena Line are allowed to permit smoking on them, which they do.

Answer (score 2):

In Amsterdam, the Netherlands, (also known by its nickname Holland) all trains and busses are non smoking. You can smoke at stations on special places were there is a smoking sign. If you smoke anywhere else you risk a penalty of 90 euro's.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but since it was dug up...

In France:

- smoking is not allowed on trains or buses
- smoking is never allowed inside station buildings
- smoking is usually allowed on train platforms, but local authorities can decide otherwise. In most large train stations in Paris for instance, it is forbidden to smoke on the platforms, even on uncovered parts. This is however not strictly enforced, and you'll find many people smoking there. There is also very little information about it (no recorded announcements in the train stations, or in the trains before arriving at such stations, and often very little signage).

Comment: This seems to be the same in most of Europe these days. No smoking officially, with some small exceptions, but not enough enforcement to make it stick.

Answer (score 1):

In Spain smoking is prohibited in all public/collective transport premises. That includes open-air stations. Usually there will be warning signs and ashtrays at the limit of the area, but not always.

It's also prohibited in closed spaces where workers can be present. This includes bars, restaurants and clubs.