# Eurail Pass from Lyon to Milan

Tags: trains, france, italy, lyon, milan

I plan to buy a Eurail pass that enables me to travel from France to Italy. I plan to buy the [France-Italy Rail Pass](http://www.eurail.com/eurail-passes/regional-pass/france-italy), but I don't know whether I would need to buy an extra pass because from my [research](http://fahrplan.oebb.at), the train will have to stop at Geneva, which is located in Switzerland.

Do I have to buy an extra pass for this purpose?

**Edit: As I research further this train comes to my mind ([TGV 9249](http://www.tgv-europe.it/fr/horaires)). I think this is really what I really need; am I right?**

Comment: Concerning your edit: It depends on your need. The train you mention is a direct train and it doesn't cross Switzerland. But as lejohn and me pointed out, there are other train connections that are faster (approximately 5 instead of 7 hours). So you have decided by yourself if you want to travel fast but with changing the train multiple train, or slower but probably with more comfort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to travel by train from Lyon to Milano, it is not necessary to pass through Geneva or any other part of Switzerland. The most straightforward option is to take a regional train (TER) from Lyon's Part-Dieu station to Chambéry and then a TGV to Milano. This train is going to Milano via the Maurienne valley and Torino. At the moment there are two or three TGV trains per day linking Paris to Milano via Chambéry and Torino.

The TGV 9249 seems to fit your needs, as it does not cross Switzerland. On the 12th of May, you can leave Lyon Part-Dieu at 14h40 by the regional train bound to Bourg-Saint-Maurice. Ar 16h00 you will arrive at Chambéry-Challes-les-Eaux, where you will have to get out and wait for the TGV 9249 to Milano, leaving from there at 17h43.

Comment: I think it is even faster if you take a regional train from Lyon to Aix-les-Bains-le-Revard. Then from there another regional train to Chambéry-Challes-les-Eaux and then the TGV to Milano and afterwards the Eurostar Italia to Milano. 5 hours and 23 minutes.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Err ... Do you mean the TGV to **Torino** and afterwards the Eurostar Italia to **Milano** ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Unfortunately I can't edit anymore

Comment: As I further search I am not too sure of the answers here. What about this train [TGV 9249](http://fahrplan.oebb.at/bin/traininfo.exe/en/752697/537135/261302/120248/81?ld=5&L=vs_inputgen&seqnr=5&ident=1r.013494166.1333361052&date=12.05.12&station_evaId=8702384&station_type=dep&journeyStartIdx=1&journeyEndIdx=9&backLink=tp&)? Isn't it faster and more convenient?

Comment: This train leaves at 14:41 and arrives at Milano around 21:45. So it takes 7 hours and 4 minutes. That's longer than 5 hours and 23 minutes. However, it could be more comfortable, because you don't have to change trains.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, I can't find the TGV train number to Torino and Eurostar to Milano, can you give me a link on that?

Comment: It is the TGV 9241 (http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/traininfo.exe/dn/475809/319016/335042/8918/85?seqnr=4&ident=dg.01684189.1333362737&date=03.04.12&station_evaId=8774100&station_type=dep&journeyStartIdx=3&journeyEndIdx=8&) and the Eurostar ES 9567 (http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/traininfo.exe/dn/280731/247835/358890/85868/85?seqnr=4&ident=dg.01684189.1333362737&date=03.04.12&station_evaId=8300035&station_type=dep&journeyStartIdx=1&journeyEndIdx=2&)

Comment: Be aware though that with most rail passes (though I don't know about your specific one), you need to pay a supplement to use fast trains like the TGV

Comment: @Gagravarr, how much would the supplement cost? Where I can get the information? I am using (Eurail)[eurail.com]

Comment: @Graviton: Read what I have written in the following post: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6359/766 ;-)

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I think you got entangled. 7 hours and 4 minutes is the time it takes from Paris to Milano and not from Lyon to Milano ... The station called "Gare de Lyon" is in Paris. It is the station in Paris where trains to places like Lyon, Marseille or Geneva are leaving.

Comment: Yes that's true. However it still seems to take some minutes longer than the regional trains combination. But in this case I would tend to use your connection ;)