# Week-ends in Paris and in Rome, from a base in Nice

Tags: transportation, paris, rome, nice

I'm travelling to Nice, France in the month of March. I will have three weekends (2 days + 2 days + 2 days) in my visit and I want to plan accordingly to travel to Rome, Paris and Monaco (nearby).

Could someone please guide me as to how I can plan effectively (budget trip) for the week-end trips to Rome and Paris? Where I can book flight (or other) tickets for travelling to Paris and Rome?

I will be travelling alone and this is my first visit to Europe so I'm a bit apprehensive.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Unfortunately this is not the site to construct an itinerary for you.  Please see: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/the-wanta-debate-we-are-not-travel-agents  Please review the [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) section on asking questions for some guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to do weekend trips to Rome and Paris from Nice, but that won't be "budget". Both cities are expensive. If in addition you have to travel on weekends (Friday night or early Saturday morning and back an Sunday evening), train and air fares will be high.

For Rome, flying will be your best bet. Check the usual sites (e.g. Kayak, Matrix Airfare search, ...). For Paris, the train may be interesting too. YOu can choose between high-speed trains (TGV and IDTGV) and a direct night train. Planning in advance will help to keep costs low.

Given the distances, ride-sharing and hitchhiking are no options for the trips to Paris and Rome.

The following two discussions provide some useful information:

[How to get from Nice to Monaco by public transport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/how-to-get-from-nice-to-monaco-by-public-transport)

[Are there ways to keep long-distance land transport costs down in France when not planning in advance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3377/are-there-ways-to-keep-long-distance-land-transport-costs-down-in-france-when-no)

If you have only three weekends, you can easily spend them closer to Nice. There are a plenty of possibilities, Monaco being one of them ...

Comment: Thank you very much .. Yes i do know i have a lot of options near nice itself and its very beautiful . I wanted to travel to paris atleast .. after all who misses paris when they come to france :D Also any ideal area where i can stay in paris so that i can roam around in the night without using trains ?? is it dangerous ??

Comment: If you are looking for a budget accommodation start searching by price and then pick a district. Paris "intro muros" is not huge and public transport is very efficient.